# Form submits with one line, but when add another line, just get whitelabel error page

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jakarta-mail

So not sure when this stopped working in my app, but I have a form that has many input fields and when submitted, grabs everything and sends the info to someone via email. The form also allows you to add a whole new policy section, so you can have 2 or 3 or however many you need, of the policy inputs. Recently the form will only work if there is only one policy section included/filled out. If you add a second one, and therefore have more than one policy section, and hit the send form button, it will just go to the whitelabel error page. It acts as if it is not even getting into the send function so I'm having a hard time debugging. 
It also looks like if you have the original policy section and fill it out then hit "add policy" for a second input section, and fill out the second policy section, then go back and hit add policy for a third section to appear, it will not work! 
If you have the first policy section filled out  and hit add a policy twice, it will then add the two policy lines with no problem, but still not send all three.
It has to be an error with my add policy section, since the email sends fine with only one policy section...  Any suggestions or thoughts as to what has lead the AMS360 policy section to not send if there is more than one policy added?

This is the error I am getting:
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='policyForm'. Error count: 1

but like I said, works just fine when only one policy section is included.

controller:

```html
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("loggedUser")
public class DirectBindController {
    @Autowired
    ResourceWebsiteUserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Autowired
    DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    @Autowired
    StorageService storageService;


    @ModelAttribute("loggedUser")
    public ResourceWebsiteUser user(){
        return userRepository.findByEmail(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    }

    @GetMapping("/directBind")
    public String getDirectBind(Model model){
        DirectBind directBind = new DirectBind();
        List<String> businessAgencies = new ArrayList<String>();
        businessAgencies.add("Personal");
        businessAgencies.add("Commercial");
        businessAgencies.add("Life");
        businessAgencies.add("Benefits");
        businessAgencies.add("Health");
        businessAgencies.add("Non P and C");
        model.addAttribute("businessAgencies", businessAgencies);


        List<Ams360Policy> ams360Policies = new ArrayList();
        Ams360Policy ams360Policy = new Ams360Policy();
        ams360Policies.add(ams360Policy);
        model.addAttribute("ams360Policies", ams360Policies);

        List<String> billTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        billTypeList.add("Direct Bill");
        billTypeList.add("Agency Bill");
        model.addAttribute("billTypeList", billTypeList);
        ams360Policy.setBillTypeOptions(billTypeList);

        directBind.setDirectBox(true);
        directBind.setServiceLevel(true);

        model.addAttribute("directBind", directBind);

        return "directBind";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/directBindAjax", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Document docSend(@ModelAttribute(value="newDoc") Document document, Model model,  @RequestPart("upfile") MultipartFile upfile) throws IOException {
        document.setStorage(storageService.storer(upfile));

        List<Object> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
        attachments.add(upfile);

        return document;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/directBind", params="addPolicy")
    public String addPolicy(final DirectBind directBind, Model model){
        List<Ams360Policy> ams360Policies =  directBind.getAms360Policies();
        Ams360Policy ams360Policy = new Ams360Policy();
        ams360Policies.add(ams360Policy);
        model.addAttribute("ams360Policies", ams360Policies);

        List<String> billTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        billTypeList.add("Direct Bill");
        billTypeList.add("Agency Bill");
        model.addAttribute("billTypeList", billTypeList);

        List<String> businessAgencies = new ArrayList<String>();
        businessAgencies.add("Personal");
        businessAgencies.add("Commercial");
        businessAgencies.add("Life");
        businessAgencies.add("Benefits");
        businessAgencies.add("Health");
        businessAgencies.add("Non P and C");
        model.addAttribute("businessAgencies", businessAgencies);


        return "directBind";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/directBind", params="removeRow")
    public String removeRow(final DirectBind directBind, final HttpServletRequest req, Model model){
        final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("removeRow"));
        List<Ams360Policy> ams360Policies =  directBind.getAms360Policies();
        model.addAttribute("ams360Policies", ams360Policies);
        directBind.setAms360Policies(ams360Policies);

        Ams360Policy ams360Policy = new Ams360Policy();
        List<String> billTypeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        billTypeList.add("Direct Bill");
        billTypeList.add("Agency Bill");
        model.addAttribute("billTypeList", billTypeList);
        ams360Policy.setBillTypeOptions(billTypeList);


        List<String> businessAgencies = new ArrayList<String>();
        businessAgencies.add("Personal");
        businessAgencies.add("Commercial");
        businessAgencies.add("Life");
        businessAgencies.add("Benefits");
        businessAgencies.add("Health");
        businessAgencies.add("Non P and C");
        model.addAttribute("businessAgencies", businessAgencies);
        directBind.getBusinessAgencyList();

        directBind.getAms360Policies().remove(rowId.intValue());
        model.addAttribute("directBind", directBind);

        return "directBind";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/directBind",  params="send")
    public String send(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="directBind") DirectBind directBind){
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setFrom("no-reply@info.com");
        mail.setTo(new String[]{"user@info.com"});
        mail.setSubject("AMS360 and PMA Data Checklist");

        Map<String, Object> mailModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mail.setModel(mailModel);

        try {
            emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail, directBind);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ("redirect:/?sentMessageFail");
        }

        File[] files = new File(storageService.getFormDirect()).listFiles();
        for(File file : files){
            file.delete();
        }
        return ("redirect:/?sentMessage");
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/email")
    public String email(){
        return "emailMessage";
    }

}
```

Email Service:

```html
@Service
public class EmailService {

    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    public EmailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender){
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    @Autowired
    public StorageService storage;

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;



    public void sendSimpleMessage(Mail mail, DirectBind directBind) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
                MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        helper.addAttachment("Mail_Icon.png", new ClassPathResource("static/images/Mail_Icon.png"));

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(mail.getModel());
        context.setVariable("directBind",directBind);
        String html = templateEngine.process("emailMessage", context);

        helper.setTo(mail.getTo());
        helper.setText(html, true);
        helper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        helper.setFrom(mail.getFrom());


        File[] files = new File(storage.getFormDirect()).listFiles();
            for(File file : files){
                helper.addAttachment(file.getName(), file);
        }
        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```html
 <form  class="ui form" th:object="${directBind}" th:action="directBind" method="post"  style="padding:0 10px;">
        <h4>Customer Setup</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <label >Contact Name (First/Last):</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{contactName}" required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="formAddress">Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="formAddress" th:field="*{formAddress}" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
            <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" th:field="*{email}" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="website" style="margin-top: 1em;"> Website:</label>
            <input type="text" id="website" th:field="*{website}" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="nameInsured">Name Insured:</label>
            <input type="text" id="nameInsured" th:field="*{insuredName}" required="true"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Business with Agency:</label>
            <div th:each="businessAgency : ${businessAgencies}">
                <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{businessAgencyList}" th:value="${businessAgency}"/>
                <label th:text="${businessAgency}">Business with Agency</label>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Executive:</label>
            <th:block th:switch="${loggedUser==null or loggedUser.client==null }">
                <span th:case="false" th:text="${loggedUser.client.getExecutive()}"></span>
                <span th:case="true"> Not Applicable </span>
            </th:block>
            <th:block th:switch="${loggedUser==null or loggedUser.client==null }">
                <input th:case="false" type="hidden" name="executive" class="executive" th:value="${loggedUser.client.getExecutive()}" />
                <input th:case="true" type="hidden" name="executive" class="executive" value="Not Applicable" />
            </th:block>

            <label style="font-size: 1.25rem; margin-left: 10px;">
                 <input type="checkbox" id="directBox"  th:field="*{directBox}"/>
            Direct </label>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="display: inline-block; margin-top:0;">
            <p>Service Level:</p>
            <label>
                    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="serviceLevel"  th:field="*{serviceLevel}"/>
                Affiliate Serviced</label>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label for="affiliateRep">Affiliate Designated Representative:</label><i class="tooltipped material-icons" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Agency Employee (Producer or Account Manager) who owns the account.">info_outline</i>
            <input type="text" id="affiliateRep" th:field="*{affiliateRep}" required="true" />
        </div>

        <div id="amsSection">
            <h4 style="display: inline;">AMS360 Policy Setup</h4>
            <input type="submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate"  name="addPolicy" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem;" value="Add Another Policy Line"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <hr/>

            <table class="table table-striped AMSTable" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Policy Number</th>
                    <th>Policy Term Start Date</th>
                    <th>Policy Term End Date</th>
                    <th>Line of Coverage</th>
                    <th style="width:150px;">Parent Company<i class="tooltipped material-icons" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Parent Company indicates Standard Carrier, Wholesaler, or MGA">info_outline</i></th>
                    <th style="width:150px;">Writing Company<i class="tooltipped material-icons" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Writing Company indicates carrier paper specific to policy">info_outline</i></th>
                    <th>Bill Type</th>
                    <th style="width:150px;">Quote Premium<i class="tooltipped material-icons" data-position="top" data-tooltip="Annual premium for line of coverage">info_outline</i></th>
                    <th>Commission</th>
                    <th><a class="trigger btn btn-docModal"><span class="fa fa-upload"></span></a></th>


                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr name="newRow" th:each="ams360Policy,stat : ${ams360Policies}" th:value="${stat.index}">
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyNumber}" required="true" /></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyTermDateStart}" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required="true"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].policyTermDateEnd}"  placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" required="true"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].lineOfCoverage}" required="true" /></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].parentCompany}" required="true" /></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].writingCompany}" required="true" /></td>
                    <td id="billTypeCell">
                        <div class="billTypeDiv" th:each="billType : ${billTypeList}">
                            <input class="bto" type="checkbox" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].billTypeOptions}" th:value="${billType}" value="off"/>
                            <label th:text="${billType}" id="billTypeLabel"></label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].quotePremium}" required="true"/></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{ams360Policies[__${stat.index}__].commission}"  placeholder="%"/></td>
                    <td class="text-right"> <button type="Submit" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" name="removeRow" th:value="${stat.index}" class="btn btn-danger" ><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="appendFile"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>


        <h4>PMA Setup</h4>
        <div class="row" sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER')">
            <label>Sub Brand:</label>
            <th:block th:switch="${loggedUser==null or loggedUser.client==null }">
                <span th:case="false" th:text="${loggedUser.client.getLegalName()}" ></span>
                <span th:case="true">Not Applicable</span>
            </th:block>
            <th:block th:switch="${loggedUser==null or loggedUser.client==null}">
                <input th:case="false" type="hidden" name="subBrand"  class="subBrand" th:value="${loggedUser.client.getLegalName()}" />
                <input th:case="true" type="hidden" name="subBrand"   class="subBrand" value="Not Applicable" />
            </th:block>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
            <label for="descriptionOfOps">Description of Operations:</label>
            <input type="text" id="descriptionOfOps" th:field="*{descriptionOfOps}" required="true" />
        </div>

        <div class="formFooter">
            <input id="send"  type="submit" value="send" name="send" class="btn btn-success finish" data-loading-text="Sent!" disabled="true" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Email HTML:

```html
<body bgcolor="#f6f8f1">
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#f6f8f1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
            <![endif]-->
            <table bgcolor="#ffffff" class="content" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#6435c9" class="header">
                        <table width="70" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="70" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
                                    <img class="fix" src="cid:Mail_Icon.png" width="70" height="70" border="0" alt="" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        <table width="425" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                        <![endif]-->
                        <table class="col425" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 425px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="70">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="subhead" style="padding: 0 0 0 3px;">
                                                NEW DATA CHECKLIST CREATED FOR:
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="h1" style="padding: 5px 0 0 0;" th:text="${directBind.contactName}">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="innerpadding borderbottom">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Contact Name:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.contactName}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Address:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.formAddress}">
                                </td>
                            </tr >
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Phone Number:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.phoneNumber}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Email:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.email}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Website:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.website}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Insured Name:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.insuredName}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Business Agency:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.businessAgencyList}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Executive:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.executive}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Direct, Affiliate Serviced</p>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Affiliate Rep:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.affiliateRep}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr th:each="ams360Policy : ${directBind.ams360Policies}">
                                <h3>AMS 360 Policy:</h3>
                                <p>Policy Number:</p>
                                <tr class="bodycopy" th:text="${ams360Policy.policyNumber}"></tr>

                                <p>Policy Term Start Date:</p>
                                <tr class="bodycopy" th:text="${#temporals.format(ams360Policy.policyTermDateStart, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}"></tr>

                                <p>Policy Term End Date:</p>
                                <tr class="bodycopy" th:text="${#temporals.format(ams360Policy.policyTermDateEnd, 'MM/dd/yyyy')}"></tr>

                                <p>Line of Coverage:</p>
                                <tr class="bodycopy" th:text="${ams360Policy.lineOfCoverage}"></tr>

                                <p>Parent Company:</p>
                                <tr class="bodycopy" th:text="${ams360Policy.parentCompany}"></tr>

                                <p>Writing Company:</p>
                                <tr class="bodycopy" th:text="${ams360Policy.writingCompany}"></tr>

                                <p>Bill Type:</p>
                                <tr class="bodycopy" th:text="${ams360Policy.billTypeOptions}"></tr>

                                <p>Quote Premium:</p>
                                <tr class="bodycopy" th:text="${ams360Policy.quotePremium}"></tr>

                                <p>Commission:</p>
                                <tr class="bodycopy" th:text="${ams360Policy.commission}"></tr>

                            </tr>
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Sub Brand:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.subBrand}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <h3>Description of Operations:</h3>
                                <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.descriptionOfOps}">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Comment: be more specific

Comment: @SanathKumar added some more information. Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: Are you using a logging mechanism of some sort. You should set your logging level in your `application.properties` to more a verbose level similar to the following: `logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG`. Then you can check the log and post the details in here. From the detailed log we can understand where exactly the validation fails.

Comment: I'm new to java and don't know how to use the logging property but will look into it @Ahmet . I've been rolling back to and using previous versions where it worked, and they are all not working now. Do you think this could be some sort of dependency issue?

Comment: @Ahmet Thank you so much!! The logging really helped me and I figured out the issue. Date formatting issue.